# Как завершить проект в Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как из проекта в Android Studio сделать apk-файл для скачивания на другие устройства?

Answer (score 6):

Как минимум, есть два способа:

### 1. Вручную

В меню Android Studio выбираете `Build` – `Generate Signed APK`.

Далее создаете кейстор и сам ключ, которым будет подписано приложение.

На следующем шаге выбираете `Build type` – `release`, `Finish`. Далее, по нажатию `Show in Explorer` откроется директория с APK.

### 2. При помощи `gradlew assembleRelease`

В `build.gradle` настраиваете релизную конфигурацию:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("my-release-key.jks")
            storePassword "password"
            keyAlias "my-alias"
            keyPassword "password"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Далее из корневой директории проекта выполняете `gradlew assembleRelease`.

Если не изменяет память, по умолчанию APK будет в `%APP_DIR%\app\build\outputs\apk`.

Более подробную информацию можно почитать в [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html).